# How to tell a class which objects it should create? Type vs. object confusion :(

Tags: c#, methods, types

I have a class (SetOfRules) that wants to handle rules (somehow).
Task: create a new instance of this class (that's easy), and later add rules (defined in a class Rules and derived classes) to the instance.

Problem 1:  I do not want to instantiate all the rules and then pass them as objects to the Add-method of SetOfRules but instead I want to pass a list of class Names (Types) to the Add-method. How do I do that?
And then how is the syntax of instantiating such an object inside of SetOfRules?

Problem 2: class Rules and derived classes do not hold any attributes. They are just collections of transformation methods. 
Do I ever have to instantiate them as an object inside the class SetOfRules or can I just call them as method of static classes (I cannot use static classes as I use inheritance on the Rule class to ensure that each rule class implements the methods that are needed)

Here is some (pseudo) code I have for my problem right now:

```
public class Rule
{
    virtual void transform( myObject ob)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class SpecificRule1 : Rule
{
    ...
}

public class SpecificRule2 : Rule
{
    ...
}



public class SetOfRules
{
    public AddRules( ???? ListOfRuleTypes)
    {
    }
}
```

Somewhere else I want to do something like:

```
SetOfRules easyRules = new SetOfRules();
easyRules.Add( new ??RuleTypes??[] { "SpecificRule2", "SpecificRule13", "SpecificRule22" });
```

Thanks for your cool hints!

Comment: Can you show us the full definition of the `Rule` class? All the public methods especially.

Comment: The classes are not implemented yet, as I'm not sure about the structural design yet (as you can see).
But the main public function would be the method transform() that will call some operations on myObject-class objects.

Comment: Then please tell us what are `Rules`. What are they supposed to check? Are they supposed to contain a predicate method like `bool Rule.Check(object)`? Can't really give hints on design without knowing the domain.

I can give you one hint though - usually when designing something it's best to start with the interface. Think of what you need your `Rule` and `SetOfRules` to do (what methods to provide) and create interfaces `IRule`, `ISetOfRules` for them.

Comment: Rules are not meant as "rules to check something" but as "transformation rules".
In this case the reals domain is hard to explain, but think of it like:

    myObject  is a mathematical shape (square, triangle, circle, ..)

and a rule (a transformation rule) is something like:

   transform( myObject ob) {
        1. double size of ob
        2. move object 10 units on y-axis
        3. turn object by 10 degrees
    }

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want a singleton class with contract:

```
public interface IRule
{
    void Transform(object o);
}
public abstract class SingletonBase<T> where T : SingletonBase<T>, new()
{
    public static T Instance { get; } = new T();
}
public class SpecificRule1 : SingletonBase<SpecificRule1>, IRule
{
    public void Transform(object o) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
public class SpecificRule2 : SingletonBase<SpecificRule2>, IRule
{
    public void Transform(object o) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
public class RuleSet : List<IRule>
{
    public void Add<TRule>() where TRule : SingletonBase<TRule>, IRule, new()
    {
        this.Add(SingletonBase<TRule>.Instance);
    }
}
```

And you can add rules in various way:

```
var rules = new RuleSet
{
    SpecificRule1.Instance,
    SpecificRule2.Instance,
};

rules = new RuleSet();
rules.Add(SpecificRule1.Instance);
rules.Add<SpecificRule2>();
```

Comment: Love that idea. 3 questions on that: 

1. given IRule x; Question:How do I access the static object? (x.Instance obviously doesn't work) 

2. given a type t that implements IRule. Question:How do I access the static object?

3. How do I declare something like SingletonBase<T> x = new SpecificRule2(); or is that never possible and I always have to go via the interface IRule?

Comment: 1: You can't access it normally. Given that `interface` cannot expose `static` members, nor can it be casted back into a `SingletonBase<>` since the concrete type is unknown. **However**, you can access it through reflection, but this means that you won't be benefiting the compile-time type checking. 2: For run-time `Type`, you can't other than through reflection. Since there is no "guarantee" that such singleton instance exist. As for generic type `T`, you can access it with constraints as shown on `RuleSet.Add<TRule>() where ...` method.

Comment: 3: You can always `new` up an instance of any `Singleton<T>`, since the generic constraints ensure this is *doable*. (note: I would use `var x = ...` instead). But, you probably shouldn't be doing it, you even stated yourself that you didn't want to instantiate. You can access the `static` instance like this: `SpecificRule2.Instance`.

Comment: To add to `#1`, there is no need to access the static object if `IRule x`, since that static object is `x` itself (under normal circumstance, like explicitly `new`ing up another instance).

Answer (score 1):

Example - rules for calculating a discount for an order item:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public decimal Total => Quantity * Price;
}
```

A contract (aka interface) for the discount can be defined like this:

```
public interface IDiscountRule
{
    decimal CalculateDiscount(OrderItem item);
}
```

Now let's implement some discount rules

- Basic discount (2%)
- Silver discount (5%)
- Gold discount (10%)

Class definitions:

```
/// <summary>
/// Abstract base class for the discount rules
/// </summary>
public abstract class DiscountRule : IDiscountRule
{
    private readonly int _percent;

    protected DiscountRule(int percent)
    {
        _percent = percent;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public decimal CalculateDiscount(OrderItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
        }

        decimal discount = item.Total * (decimal) (_percent/100.0);

        return discount;
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// 2% discount
/// </summary>
public class BasicDiscountRule : DiscountRule
{
    public BasicDiscountRule() : base(2)
    {

    }
}

/// <summary>
/// 5% discount
/// </summary>
public class SilverDiscountRule : DiscountRule
{
    public SilverDiscountRule() : base(5)
    {

    }
}

/// <summary>
/// 10% discount
/// </summary>
public class GoldDiscountRule : DiscountRule
{
    public GoldDiscountRule() : base(10)
    {

    }
}
```

Calculating the discount for an order item, using a rule:

```
var item = new OrderItem
{
    ItemId = 1,
    Price = 50,
    Quantity = 2
};

var rule = new SilverDiscountRule();
decimal discount = rule.CalculateDiscount(item);
```

Now let's create a Composite rule, in order to apply multiple rules (discounts) to an order item:

```
/// <summary>
/// To apply multiple discount rules to an order item
/// </summary>
public class CompositeDiscountRule : IDiscountRule
{
    private readonly List<Type> _discountTypes;

    public CompositeDiscountRule()
    {
        _discountTypes = new List<Type>();
    }

    public CompositeDiscountRule(List<Type> discountTypes)
    {
        if (discountTypes == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(discountTypes));
        }

        _discountTypes = discountTypes;
    }

    public void Register<T>() where T : IDiscountRule, new()
    {
        _discountTypes.Add(typeof(T));
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public decimal CalculateDiscount(OrderItem item)
    {
        decimal totalDiscount = 0;

        foreach (var discountType in _discountTypes)
        {
            IDiscountRule rule = Activator.CreateInstance(discountType) as IDiscountRule;

            if (rule != null)
            {
                totalDiscount += rule.CalculateDiscount(item);
            }
        }

        return totalDiscount;
    }
}
```

You can use the composite rule with a list of types:

```
var item = new OrderItem
{
    ItemId = 1,
    Price = 50,
    Quantity = 2
};

// composite rule with types
var compositeRule = new CompositeDiscountRule(new List<Type>
{
    typeof(GoldDiscountRule),
    typeof(BasicDiscountRule)
});

decimal discount = compositeRule.CalculateDiscount(item); // discount = 12.0
```

Or, as an alternative, using generics:

```
var item = new OrderItem
{
    ItemId = 1,
    Price = 50,
    Quantity = 2
};

// composite rule using generics
compositeRule = new CompositeDiscountRule();
compositeRule.Register<BasicDiscountRule>();
compositeRule.Register<SilverDiscountRule>();

decimal discount = compositeRule.CalculateDiscount(item); // discount = 7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read about **pattern Decorator**. It is structural design pattern that lets you attach new behaviors to objects by placing them inside wrapper objects that contain these behaviors.

I think it will help you to solve first problem

useful link: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator